# Erro de sintaxe ao usar SQLite android "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"

Tags: android, sqlite

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
package com.example.wesley.bancodedadossqlite;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Wesley on 17/01/2018.
 */

public class CriaBanco extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "banco.db";
    private static final String TABELA = "livros";
    private static final String ID = "_id";
    private static final String TITULO = "titulo";
    private static final String AUTOR = "autor";
    private static final String EDITORA = "editora";
    private static final int VERSAO = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABELA + "("
                + ID + "integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + TITULO + "text,"
                + AUTOR + "text,"
                + EDITORA + "text"
                +")";

        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABELA);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: o `EXISTS` não pode estar colado ao nome da tabela. Comece por separar deixando `"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA`

Comment: era isso msm. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você coloca:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABELA)
```

Seu resultado seria:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTSTABELA
```

Então para corrigir, dê um "espaço" depois do `EXISTS`, pois trata-se de uma `String`:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA)
```

Seu resultado seria:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABELA
```